# PHP - read 8 bit integers

Tags: php, binary, integer, pack, unpack

I have a binary file that is all 8 bit integers.  I have tried to use the php unpack() functions but I cant get any of the arguments to work for 1 byte integers.  I have tried to combine the data with a dummy byte so that I can use the 'n'/'v' arguments.  I am working with a windows machine to do this.  Ultimately I would like a function to return an array of integers based on a string of 8 bit binary integers.  The code I have tried is below -

```
$dat_handle = "intergers.dat";
$dat_file = fopen($dat_handle, "rb");
$dat_data = fread($dat_file, 1);
$dummy = decbin(0);
$combined = $dummy.$dat_data;
$result = unpack("n", $combined);
```

Comment: `"n"` is unsigned short -- 16 bits.  Of course reading a 8 bit int is gonna fail if you read it as a 16 bit int ;).  Try `unpack("c", $combined);`

Comment: @Frank His idea is actually sound (assuming unsigned data), his execution is wrong. He's prepending `'0'` when he should be prepending `chr(0)`. That said, this is still the wrong way to do it!

Comment: You're right: decbin returns the a PHP string containing the char "0", which is not at all what he was aiming for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What your looking for is the char datatype. Now there are two version of this, signed (lowercase `c`) and unsigned (uppercase `C`). Just use the one that's correct for your data.

```
<?php
    $byte = unpack('c', $byte);
?>
```

Also, if the data file is just a bunch of bytes and nothing else, and you know it's length, you can do this. (If the length is 16 signed chars in a row.)

```
<?php
    $bytes = unpack('c16', $byte);
?>
```

If you don't know how many bytes will be in the file, but you know there is only going to be bytes you can use the asterisk code to read until EOF.

```
<?php
    $bytes = unpack('c*', $byte);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The following should do what you want ([`ord`](http://php.net/ord)):

```
$dat_handle = "intergers.dat";
$dat_file = fopen($dat_handle, "rb");
$dat_data = ord(fread($dat_file, 1));
```

What you are trying to do is retrieve the integer value of the single byte. Because you are reading in single bytes at a time, you will always have exactly one valid ASCII character. `ord` returns the binary value of that one character.